# How to hide embedly javascript key?

Tags: javascript, embed

I'm working with Embedly and found out that the key I use, and pay for, in the Embedly javascript is plainly visible as anyone can just "Inspect Element" and see the key.

How can I hide that part of the javascript, the key part, from people just using "Inspect Element"?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function(){
    $('div.featuredGame').embedly({
      maxWidth: 200,
      maxHeight: 140,
      key: 'KEY REMOVED'
    });
  });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedly now added a securing keys section in response to this problem. https://blog.embed.ly/securing-keys-f8aca8e6d180

Answer (score 5):

you could try and obfuscate it? Here's a [js obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) you could use.

Its not 100% secure, but it at least hides your key, unless someone REALLY wanted to decode it.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how I can use that? I'm not quite sure how that works.

Comment: just paste your actual javascript function into the editor and click the obfuscate button. It'll give your function a sort of basic 'encryption' that can still be interpreted by the browser. Use the code the site generates for you, instead of the function you already have :)

Comment: but is there much else that can be done in this case? Sure, it can easily be undone, but its still not a bad idea to have an added layer of security, as opposed to none.

Comment: It's just that it's a false sense of security, like WEP for wireless networks, but I guess it *is* better than nothing.

Comment: @Rocket I actually contacted embedly about this, here is their response: 

Hi Tory,

We are in the process of adding a referrer lock to API keys. This will reject any calls that don't have the referrer that you have setup in our system. Of course, this isn't a foolproof system. There isn't a simple way to provide tough security for a client side implementation, especially on a public site. We realize this, and if there is ever a question of where your calls are coming from, let us know and we will make sure you don't have to pay for anything you didn't use.

Thanks
Bob Corsaro

Comment: its not false, its just not perfect. If someone wanted to crack it, they could. But the same goes for ANY form of encryption or password protection. If someone wanted to crack it, they could. That's why security algorithms and protocols are constantly evolving.